# MultiBinding in a TreeView Collapses TreeViewItems when One of the Bindings value changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview, multibinding

I have a TreeView thats binding to an Object of Type View with an attribute Name and two Lists.
When i add Elements in one of the expanded Lists it stays expanded and thats what i want . 
The Problem is when i change The Name of View1 all the Multibinging Bindings are refreshed and all expanded Lists if any in the View1 collapses, but the View1 is still expanded . 
Is there any Way to avoid this behaviour so that when the value of the Name changes the converter somehow only changes the changed Value without collasing other Bindings .
Thank you

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:View}">
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource folderConverter}" ConverterParameter=",A,B">
            <Binding Path="Name"/>
            <Binding Path="List1"/>
            <Binding Path="List2"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>`
```

Comment: I am curious though, why do you need the "Name" property to be bound to something like ItemsSource? Can you NOT bind it?

Comment: i want the name to be binded in the treeview as the first treeviewitem along with other lists . I thought MultiBinding was the best Solution for such multiple Bindings. Or am i missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup looks like something in which a [`CompositeCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) might help, it should prevent the complete recreation of the `ItemsSource` even if you change a part.

Comment: i modified the converter so it returns CompositeCollection but nothing changed! When I change the Name the Converter is called again and a new composite collection is being generated .  I should mention that i am not combining List1 and List2 together in one List . I have a 3 Level TreeView where the 2nd Level has 3 TreeViewItems(which are Name and A and B) and when you expand A u get to see List1 .

Comment: @MohamedCheri: You are not supposed to use a MultiBinding with converter, replace the whole thing with the CompositeCollection. You may use some converter inside collection containers if you must but using one converter to create a complex list is never a good idea